# mariadb online drop index does not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using maria db. When I try to drop an index with the online ddl options (lock=none, Algorithm=inplace), I get an syntax error.
     DROP INDEX idx_new ON posts ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE;
     ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE' at line 1

As far as I understand the documentation, the latest mariadb should be able to run those DDL online.

I tried this ddl:

```
DROP INDEX idx_new ON posts ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE;
```

and also those:

```
DROP INDEX idx_new ON posts LOCK=NONE ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
DROP INDEX idx_new ON posts LOCK=NONE;
```

Here some background info:

```
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.3
```

I had mysql installed (I do not remember the version) via brew, then replaced it with mariadb (uninstall and install also via brew).

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.5-MariaDB, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

strange thing is: When I use my sql ui (Sequel Pro), it shows me in the title (MySQL 5.5.5 - 10.2.5-MariaDB).

Could there be some artifacts from MySQL 5.5.5 left?

Should MariaDB 10.2.5 not be able to run a DROP INDEX online?

Comment: you want to drop index, why do you specify algorithm?

Comment: Show us the entire `ALTER` statement.  Perhaps the `ALGORITHM` clause is not in the right place.

Comment: Added the ALTER statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error in `DROP INDEX` is a known bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12572 , syntax deficiency. The workaround is to do it via the general `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE posts DROP INDEX idx_new, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

Regarding `5.5.5` prefix -- it's not an indication of 5.5 artifacts. The prefix was introduced along with 10.x release version line, to deal with servers and clients not recognizing 10.x as a valid version and refusing to communicate with it (see https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4088 for some details).

MariaDB servers and clients strip the prefix, but third party applications don't.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. This was the issue. I knew about the alternative syntax, but I did not try it. 
(I enhanced RoR ActiveRecord migration to always use online DDL, so I tried to stick to the sql that ActiveRecord::Migration was generating for me. But it is ok, I can transform it now I know what is going on.)